# Button on the link card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon. There is a product card that is a link. On the card there is a button for adding a product, on which the onclick event is hung. When you click on the button, the card link is triggered. Tell me how to solve this problem.

```
<Link to={'Bigcard'} className="product__link">
      
    <div className="product__card">{props.count}
      <img className="product__img" src={props.url} alt="" />
      <h4 className="product__title">{props.title}</h4>
      <p className="product__description">{props.description}</p>
      <div className="product__parameters-button">
        
        <div className="product__parameters">
          <p className="product__price">{props.price} ₽</p>
          <p className="product__weight"> / {props.weight} г.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div className="product__plus" onClick={addProduct}>
          <img src={plus} alt="" className="product__plus-img" />
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **event.stopPropagation()** will help you. This stops the control from inner div click to outer div. Also consider reading **event.preventDefault()** which prevents default functionality execution.
Refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Working example can be found [at this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you set a link to the whole card, so something like this should work:

```
<div className="product__card">{props.count}
  <img className="product__img" src={props.url} alt="" />
  <h4 className="product__title">{props.title}</h4>
  <p className="product__description">{props.description}</p>

  <Link to={'Bigcard'} className="product__link">
  <div className="product__parameters-button">
  </Link>
    
    <div className="product__parameters">
      <p className="product__price">{props.price} ₽</p>
      <p className="product__weight"> / {props.weight} г.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div className="product__plus" onClick={addProduct}>
      <img src={plus} alt="" className="product__plus-img" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Now only the button triggers the link.
You can also try event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation() as @Hamza Mushtaq said, setting a listener event in the card to check if he button was clicked.